# CD in Azure PowerShell Failure

Tags: azure, cd, azure-cloud-shell

In powershell `cd` works, but not in my Azure Cloud Shell. What am I missing?

Copied session shows me trying to get into quickstart directory (which was created in the powershell shell)

```
Welcome to Azure Cloud Shell

Type "az" to use Azure CLI 2.0
Type "help" to learn about Cloud Shell

MOTD: Switch to Bash from PowerShell: bash

VERBOSE: Authenticating to Azure ...
VERBOSE: Building your Azure drive …

Azure:/
PS Azure:\> ls -F
clouddrive@  quickstart/  test/

Azure:/
PS Azure:\> cd quickstart
cd : Cannot find path 'Azure:/quickstart' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ cd quickstart
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Azure:/quickstart:String) 
                                           [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use "**cd $HOME/quickstart**" to achieve it.

For illustration please check below screenshot.

[image]

Hope this helps!! Cheers!! :)

Comment: Strange its not mentioned as a step in the docs [Create a static HTML web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html)

Comment: Yes! Thanks for providing the doc link. We have updated the document as required. It would ideally take some time to reflect the changes.

Comment: The change is reflected in the document.